# Organizing SQL data based on date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to organize my SQL data based off of the dates from which the orders were made.

My data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_NO, ITEM, VERSION_NO,
(CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO ORDER BY NOT_BEFORE_DATE 
 ASC) = 1
         THEN 'what-if'
         ELSE 'wh'
         END) AS VERSION_NEW
,
(CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO ORDER BY  
NOT_BEFORE_DATE ASC) = 2
        THEN 'initial'
        ELSE 'other'
        END) AS VERSION

FROM FDT_MAPTOOL
WHERE ITEM IN (1032711)
;
```

My results: 
[image: My Results]

I want my data to be ordered by PO# and the date it was created. 
As you can see in my picture the First two line have the same ITEM and same PO (Order_No). I need the first two to say Initial on the side because they are the first two based on the dates. They were created first. Everything after should say other.

I am not sure if PL/SQL is needed for this?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to order your results by something, have you considered an `order by` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different analytic function so that more than one row can have the value of 1 e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_NO, ITEM, VERSION_NO,
(CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO ORDER BY NOT_BEFORE_DATE 
 ASC) = 1
         THEN 'what-if'
         ELSE 'wh'
         END) AS VERSION_NEW
,
(CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO ORDER BY  
NOT_BEFORE_DATE ASC) = 1
        THEN 'initial'
        ELSE 'other'
        END) AS VERSION

FROM FDT_MAPTOOL
WHERE ITEM IN (1032711)
;
```

Either `rank()` OR `dense_rank()` should work here instead of `row_number()`

nb: note sure if you really need "select distinct"

Comment: What analytical function should I use?

Comment: Either rank() or dense_rank() the difference between these is that the latter will not skip any numbers in the result (1,2,3....) but the former can (1,2,5....) so a dense_rank result can be a little more predictable. But for this query either function would work.